# Why does matplotlib plot linearly in this case?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot, scatter-plot

I have a file that looks like this:

```
50  -5770.28217920
60  -5777.65455948
80  -5781.46247693
90  -5782.48469438
100 -5783.53910123
110 -5784.48875463
120 -5785.20993545
130 -5785.67562915
140 -5785.92792826
150 -5786.04192799
160 -5786.08411149
170 -5786.10038894
180 -5786.11543587
190 -5786.13784315
200 -5786.16694454
210 -5786.19846679
220 -5786.22802030
230 -5786.25234746
240 -5786.27030127
250 -5786.28215924
260 -5786.28904135
270 -5786.29240667
280 -5786.29367385
290 -5786.29396076
300 -5786.29400469
```

I wanted to plot this data using matplotlib and went about it like this:

```
f = open(fname, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
results = []
for x in lines:
    results.append(x.split('\n')[0])

col1 = []
col2 = []
for r in results:
    col1.append(r.split('\t')[0])
    col2.append(r.split('\t')[1])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(col1,col2)
```

I want it to look like an asymptotic curve, as seen in Gnuplot:

[image: Gnuplot Image]

Instead, I get the following linear plot:

[image: Matplotlib Image].

I tried including `plt.xscale('linear')` and `plt.yscale('linear')` but it has no effect. Could someone please identify the issue?

Comment: the contents of `col1` and `col2` appear to be strings.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to convert them to float?

Comment: `col1.append(float(r.split('\t')[0]))`
`col2.append(float(r.split('\t')[1]))`